# Can I emulate a callback function from jquery removeClass?

Tags: javascript, jquery, removeclass

I'm trying to execute these removeClass calls in succession. There doesn't seem to be a call back function using removeClass so is there another way to emulate this?

```
  $("#card1").removeClass('flip');

  //wait for card1 flip to finish and then flip 2
  $("#card2").removeClass('flip');

  //wait for card2 flip to finish and then flip 3
  $("#card3").removeClass('flip');
```

Comment: there's no waiting for removing a class from an element.you remove it and add it.what's the point?

Comment: It's part of transitions with CSS3 so I'm looking for a fun effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that you're using CSS3 transition for doing this.
The easiest way to do this is to set delay manually:

```
$("#card1").removeClass('flip');

setTimeout(function(){
   //wait for card1 flip to finish and then flip 2
   $("#card2").removeClass('flip');
}, 500);

setTimeout(function(){
   //wait for card2 flip to finish and then flip 3
   $("#card3").removeClass('flip');
}, 1000);
```

There's no built in jQuery method to check that css transition is complete.

Comment: The `transitionEnd` event (or `webkitTransitionEnd` etc) should work.

Comment: ...or `mozTransitionEnd` etc. I think timer is better nowadays and will be more bulletproof in case that `transitionEvent` event wont fire.

Comment: It might be better to nest the timeouts instead of calling one after the other.

Answer (score 3):

Old Tread but Goolge know him ;-)

jQueries UI has a extend Function for removeClass.

```
<div class="big-blue"></div>
```

```
$( "div" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).removeClass( "big-blue", 1000, "easeInBack", function(){
      // do fancy stuff after animation is completed
  });
});
```

jQuery-UI Doc: http://api.jqueryui.com/removeclass/